# jaxws: It is not a jaxws or a jaxb binding file

Tags: jax-ws, jax-ws-customization, jaxws-maven-plugin

I'm getting this error message:

> [WARNING] Ignoring: binding file "file:/home/jeusdi/projects/salut/hes/hes-visor-api-service/src/jaxws/bindings.xml". It is not a jaxws or a jaxb binding file

It's telling me that my `binding.xml` file is not valid and it will be ingored.

My `binding.xml` file content is:

```xml
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
           xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           jaxb:version="2.0">
    <jaxb:bindings >
        <jaxb:globalBindings typesafeEnumMaxMembers="2000"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14):

If this is the [Jakarta XML Web Services implementation](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/metro-jax-ws) that you're using, then you should not use `xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"` but `xmlns:jaxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"`.

This did the trick for me for the exact same error.

See [JAXWSBindingsConstants.java](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/metro-jax-ws/blob/b3491beafb3c6cc3619db553e02e4d6767611587/jaxws-ri/tools/wscompile/src/main/java/com/sun/tools/ws/wsdl/document/jaxws/JAXWSBindingsConstants.java)

Comment: additionally `version="2.0"` has to be bumped to `version="3.0"`