# Getting build error when upgrading org.apache.cxf to version 4 from version 3

Tags: java, cxf

I have a java app which used org.apache.cxf -artifactId cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs  with version 3.3.7 but when I try to upgrade it to version 4, I am getting build errors. As earlier code used to work properly, what do I need to change while migrating?

Not a valid jaxb or jaxws binding file, please check the namespace
at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.customization.CustomizationParser.addBinding(CustomizationParser.java:540)
[[1;33mWARNING[m]     at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.customization.CustomizationParser.parse(CustomizationParser.java:117)
[[1;33mWARNING[m]     at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.wsdl11.JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.customize(JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.java:115)
[[1;33mWARNING[m]     at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:188)
[[1;33mWARNING[m]     at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:156)
[[1;33mWARNING[m]     at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:402)
[[1;33mWARNING[m]     at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:105)
[[1;33mWARNING[m]     at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
[[1;33mWARNING[m]     at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
[[1;33mWARNING[m]     at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.ForkOnceWSDL2Java.main(ForkOnceWSDL2Java.java:51)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jaxws: It is not a jaxws or a jaxb binding file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65719468/jaxws-it-is-not-a-jaxws-or-a-jaxb-binding-file)